# Kaggle - stopwords download - download false

Tags: python, nlp, kaggle, stop-words

My kernel is NLP with disaster twitter. Kaggle notebook works in download stopwords and error code download stopwords. It's error code:

```
import nltk


nltk.download("stopwords")

[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [Errno -3]
[nltk_data]     Temporary failure in name resolution>
False
```

Comment: maybe server has problem and try next day. OR read NLTK documentation - there should be information with URL to this data and you can download it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs if your kernel does not have internet turned on. You can turn the internet on in your settings

#### Solution 1 - Turn on kernel internet

1. On the right side of your notebook, open Settings
2. Switch Internet to 'On'. You may need to do additional verification for your account

[image: KernelSettingsInternet]

#### Solution 2 - Directly add the nltk_data

An easy way to resolve this without turning on internet on your kernel is to do the following:

1. Select 'Add Data' in the top right of the notebook
2. Search for nltk_data, click 'Add' button
3. Update your code to include the following:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it worked for me.

As suggested in the comment you could try later.

Another option is to use the GUI.

Do

```py
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

and the GUI should open where you can manually select what you want to download.

Comment: It seems like if you get this error then there is a problem communicating with the server. I tried to use the GUI and I clicked 'l' for List and then no packages were listed,  15 seconds later the GUI output the same error as directly trying to download a specific package.